# A Bar Suspend by Two Wires - PHYS I HW

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statics

> A nonuniform horizontal bar of mass $m$ is supported by two massless wires against gravity. The left wire makes an angle $ϕ_1$ with the horizontal, and the right wire makes an angle $ϕ_2$. The bar has length $L$.

[image]

> What is the position of the center of mass of the bar, measured as distance $x$ from the bar's left end?
>   Find x in terms of $ϕ_1, ϕ_2,$ and $L$

---

I've found that
$$x={T_2sin(ϕ_2) \over T_1sin(ϕ_1)+T_2sin(ϕ_2)}$$
and
$$0=T_2cos(ϕ_2)-T_1cos(ϕ_1)$$
The hint it's giving me is

> Use what you know about the x components of the forces acting on the bar.

I'm just not sure where to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the net torque on the bar must be 0. Relative to the center of mass of the bar, the magnitude of the torque of wire 1 is $T_1 x sin(\phi_1)$ and the magnitude of the torque of wire 2 is $T_2 (L-x) sin(\phi_2)$.

Use this to write an additional equation which will help you solve the problem.